# clicking on 2 markers on the same location

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

I am using google maps and I have 2 markers displayed at the same location( they are different images so they don't overlap 100%).
Anyways, when I click on a that location, then one of these markers  gets the click event. Is there a way that I can get the click on both markers?

Thank you

Comment: if both markers are at the same location,  why not just create one tap/click listener that will call two methods?

Comment: Because  I get many locations from DB and then I draw all of their markers. So When I get a click on on a marker, I only get it for that marker. I dont know if there was another marker behind it and therefore the second marker does not get it. I know I can store all the locations and do a search to do a match, but it could be a huge list to search for it. So I wanted to know if there is a way provided by google maps